# How to write Ruby in Brackets

Tags: ruby, adobe-brackets

How can I write a ruby program using Adobe Brackets as a code editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing a Ruby program doesn't require any specific text editors. So using Adobe Brackets would as same as using Sublime or Notepad.

Just save the file with `.rb` extension, and Brackets will automatically switch into Ruby mode.

Now if you are looking for an extension that makes the editor user friendly with Ruby scripts, you could try looking at the following links :

https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Brackets-Extensions
https://github.com/TheresNoBox/Brackets-Ruby